# Where are my node log files?

Tags: ros, rospy, logging, roscpp, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a system with a few dozen nodes, started from a top-level launch file consisting mostly of `<include>` tags. Most of them are `rospy` nodes, but some are `roscpp`. Looking in `~/.ros/log` I see that node log files exist for <10 nodes. I can't see any pattern as to why a few nodes would make log files, but not others. There are no logs in the `$ROS_ROOT` tree. None of our launch files specify the `output` attribute in the `<node>` tag, so I would expect there to be a log file for every node, since the default is `log`. We're running Indigo on Ubuntu 14.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307235/where-are-my-node-log-files?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2018-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found 'em, and feeling kinda silly. We're using a Clearpath Husky robot, and the startup script `husky-core-start` sets `$ROS_LOG_DIR` to `/tmp`.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0